# ios - semaphore not waiting for ALAssetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum method to complete

Tags: ios, ios7, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

i am using semaphore to wait for async task to complete , but i don't why it's not waiting in below case, please tell me where i am doing mistake

```
NSLog(@"start async task");   

dispatch_semaphore_t sema =  dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    [assetLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage 
                                   orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp 
                               completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                           NSLog(@"waiting for block to complete");                    
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
});

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

NSLog(@"finished");

i am getting following output -

start async task ---> finished ----> waiting for block to complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments by blazejmar, your code doesn't work for two reasons:

First: your `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);` must be in the completion call, after the file has been written to the assets library

Second (and more important): You are blocking the main thread, but `ALAssetsLibrary` needs it to complete the write of the image.

I suggest you to refactor your code and use a different design pattern, avoid blocking threads.
However, if you want a "simple and fast" solution, simply put another dispatch aroud all your code (and move the dispatch signal as I explained). NOTE: in this code I added some NSLog calls to print the current thread, I'll explain why later

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSLog(@"Thread id is %i", (int)pthread_self());

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"start async task");

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema =  dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Thread id is %i", (int)pthread_self());

        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

        [assetLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage
                                       orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp
                                   completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                                       NSLog(@"waiting for block to complete");

                                       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                                   }];



    });

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"finished");


});
```

This will work and print

```
2014-07-22 08:49:24.488 Asset[66697:1139580] start async task
2014-07-22 08:49:27.709 Asset[66697:1139582] waiting for block to complete
2014-07-22 08:49:27.710 Asset[66697:1139580] finished
```

About the use of main thread by `ALAssetsLibrary`: 
I can't find it in the documentation, but you can easily find which thread are used for system calls doing something like this (maybe someone has a more simple method):

- Put NSLog calls in your code as shown above.
- create a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_msgSend` with this expression: `expr -- (void)printf("[%s, %s] - Thread: %i\n",(char *) object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4)), (char *) *(long *)($esp+8), (int) pthread_self())`. This will print all method calls with the thread on which they were called
- enable the breakpoint immediately after `[assetLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum]`

In my case:

2014-07-22 08:42:59.892 Asset[66411:1135166] Thread id is 84767144 <-- main thread
2014-07-22 08:42:59.893 Asset[66411:1135251] Thread id is -1341575168 <-- background thread 1
2014-07-22 08:42:59.893 Asset[66411:1135252] Thread id is -1341042688 <-- background thread 2

Log started immediately after `[assetLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum]`

[nil, CGImage] - Thread: -1341042688
[OS_dispatch_semaphore, retain] - Thread: -1341042688
[ALAssetsLibrary, writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:] - Thread: -1341042688
[CFPrefsDirectSource, createRequestNewContentMessageForDaemon:] - Thread: 84767144 <--- BINGO, first message to the main thread

So, if you block the main thread, your code will block on that call.

Answer (score 1):

Writing image to Assets Library is also async. That's why you have a completion block as an argument. You should put `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)` inside that block to unlock the semaphore after operation is finished.

Comment: if i put semaphore signal inside the block then it will go for infinite wait .

Comment: my block is inside 'dispatch_async' , it means it's a separate thread . i am able to achieve this in other cases except above case

Comment: That's right. But does whole routine get called from main thread?

Comment: So this is the answer why it gets locked. ALAssetsLibrary requires main thread to be unlocked to complete write operation. So the question is why you want it to be synchronous?

Comment: i need assetUrl from that block , my next code dependent on assetUrl ,and i can't put that code inside completion handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57694/discussion-between-blazejmar-and-riyaz).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 `dispatch_sync`    rather then   `dispatch_async`
```

dispatch_sync  will call your method and then finish will be called.